# How to open only the directories with QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qfiledialog, qtwidgets

This is my code :

```
    def open(self):
        file_dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
        file_dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(["dir"])
```

I want to open only the directories, I use the [setMimeTypeFilters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setMimeTypeFilters) method, it works well when I set parameters like "image/jpeg" or "video/mp4".

Comment: Directories do not have a standard mime type. On Windows they do not have a mime type at all. Why are you not using the [`fileMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#fileMode-prop) property? You can just do `file_dialog.setFileMode(file_dialog.Directory)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a method built into QFileDialog that simplifies the process of getting directories called [getExistingDirectory()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html?highlight=qfiledialog#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory). Common usage would look something like:

```
directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption='caption', directory='C:\\path\\to\\starting\\directory')
```

It directly returns the selected directory as a string, or None if the dialog was cancelled. If you're looking for more control over your dialog, this may not be the best option. Otherwise, this makes the process quite straightforward.